# Rails S Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

after uploading my app to git & heroku successfully , my app now does not work, when i run localhost:3000 get fails to connect message- . when i do rails s -  i now get error messages

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': /Users/neilpatel/code/omrails/app/models/user.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':' (SyntaxError)
  has_many :pins, :dependent => : destroy
                                 ^
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in`block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in`load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in`load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in`each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in`block in co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 12 of `app/models/user.rb`, instead of:

```
:dependent => : destroy
```

you should do:

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

Please try to understand what an error message actually says before asking a question.